# Searching through multiple keys in a collection by one string Ruby MongoDB

Tags: ruby, mongodb, collections, find, key

I have one search string which is gonna be my value and then I want to test every key in my collection if it has that value. Is there a way to make this work?

```
entry = db['names'].find({:firstname => "#{search}"}).to_a  
puts entry
```

let´s say if this worked I´d be happy:

```
entry = db['names'].find({[:firstname, :lastname] => "#{search}"}).to_a 
puts entry
```

Comment: Can you give a rough idea about, what do you mean by all keys ?

Comment: I would suggest that you use mongoid for this kind of usage

Comment: let´s say if this worked I´d be happy:
entry = db['names'].find({[:firstname, :lastname] => "#{search}"}).to_a
puts entry

I have one search string which is gonna be my value and then I want to test every key in my collection if it has that value

Comment: Put it in your question, to make your question more clear, rather than in a comment.

Comment: also, please clarify if you want an `or` operation

Comment: @xlembouras Did you run this `db['names'].find({[:firstname, :lastname] => "#{search}"}).to_a` ? And if so, what did you get ?

Comment: @xlembouras Thank you I´ll look into that. So there´s no way to use find for what I want to do? I don´t want to use or, I just want the find method to return every key that holds my value string#search.

Comment: From the [doc](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#find-instance_method) `collection.find({"hello" => "world"})`. it is saying *only matches documents that have a key “hello” with value “world”. Matches can have other keys **in addition** to “hello”.* -- Any help from this line ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit I´ve read that countless times and I don´t know what the last sentence is supposed to mean. So it doesn´t help me, no.

Comment: I think it is what, you are trying to get done.. Try it..

Comment: @ArupRakshit I didn't run it, and I think it is expressed wrong in the question. I think that we want is something like find({'hello' => 'world', 'good' => 'bye'}) if we are on a "and" operator

Comment: @AruRakshit Are you saying that it would automatically match the key?

Comment: something like `.find({'$or' => [{'key_1' => elem}, {'key_2' => elem}])` comes to mind

Comment: @xlembouras YOU ARE THE MAN, your last post did it! Where in the doc could  I have found this? Somebody award you solver of this thread!

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/ mongodb doc :-)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> `:whatever => /#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i`

This did it!

Answer (score 1):

If you want either the first or last names to match, then you want an [`:$or`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#op._S_or) operator:

```
db['names'].find(
  :$or => [
    :firstname => search,
    :lastname  => search
  ]
)
```

If you want both the first and last names to match, then:

```
db['names'].find(
  :firstname => search,
  :lastname  => search
)
```

And there's no need to say `"#{search}"` unless you want to convert `nil`s to empty string, in that case you'd be better off with `search.to_s` to be more explicit about your intent.

Comment: +1 for making clear the line I quoted in the comment.

Comment: Is that for the current MongoDB Version, cause I´m using 1.9.2 and it´s not working.

Comment: AFAIK it should work in any version. Do you want exact matches or things that just contain `search`?

Comment: @muistooshort any key that holds the value of search. I´d say contain! If that means it would be case-insensitive, cause currently it is case-sensitive.

Comment: If you're looking for "contains" then your original `db['names'].find({:firstname => "#{search}"})` wasn't right either, you'd want `:whatever => /#{Regexp.escape(search)}/i`.

Answer (score 0):

As provided in the comment section, in order to search with an or operator you can use

```
db['names'].find(
  {'$or' => [
             {'key_1' => elem},
             {'key_2' => elem}
            ]
  }
)
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for, using MongoDB 1.9.2